go run unable to serve website in user mode, however works in root mode in ubuntu WSL - Windows
I am writing a simple web app in golang: golang http main.go server, with vscode user mode invocation
the server snippet:
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func helloWorldPage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Hello world!")
}

func main(){
    http.HandleFunc("/", helloWorldPage)
    http.ListenAndServe("", nil)

}

The problem is invocations from terminal via vscode (or simple user mode for that matter) immediately terminates without serving at default port 80.
drainbamage@LAPTOP-KPETF9CD:~/dev/portfolio$ go version
go version go1.22.3 linux/amd64
drainbamage@LAPTOP-KPETF9CD:~/dev/portfolio$ go run main.go   <--- terminates without hosting.
drainbamage@LAPTOP-KPETF9CD:~/dev/portfolio$

However... if I run the same command in root mode, it works as expected:
drainbamage@LAPTOP-KPETF9CD:~/dev/portfolio$ sudo su
[sudo] password for drainbamage:
root@LAPTOP-KPETF9CD:/home/drainbamage/dev/portfolio# go run main.go   <--- working as expected.
^Csignal: interrupt
root@LAPTOP-KPETF9CD:/home/drainbamage/dev/portfolio#

root mode main.go invocation
vscode prompt
hosted webpage
Tried

go version command works just fine in both root and user mode.
Its just http serving which it is just not able to do, I tried this (not exactly my problem, actually opposite, but tried: https://forum.golangbridge.org/t/go-doesnt-work-in-root-mode/27340/3)
my guess is, given that it's working in root mode, it might be lacking some permissions? I am new to wsl environment, so I think it could be related to that.

Expected

Expecting same result as of root mode in normal mode.


I think this is by design in Linux, you'll need to use port 1024 or higher if you're not root.

The error returned from http.ListenAndServe("", nil) explains the problem.  Change the code to log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe("", nil)) to see that error.

Also, @CeriseLimón your suggestion helped. The problem is now solved.

@DrainBamage Always check the errors returned from a function, particularly when the function does not work as expected.

As @MikeChristensen suggested, one cannot dabble with ports lower than 1024 without root permissions. (More info that I found - post)
Solution?

Unless it is really required to open ports lower than 1024, you can read the above post, which have some suggestions.
Else, you can just change the port to a higher value, like so:

log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))

